# how to store the state of fragment with navigation bottom menu

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to store the value of my fragments components inside an activity with lower navigation menu, controlled by navController.
My problem is that when I change one fragment to another (onPause) with the bottom navigation, or rotate the screen, all my data in the component layout is lost.
is there a solution to solve this problem?

Comment: You should use ViewModel which is designed to hold and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle-conscious way. This allows data to survive configuration changes such as screen rotations.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the data in a Viewmodel and observe it from the UI. The stored data is not lost if the framework destroys and re-creates the activities and fragments during a configuration change or other events.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?hl=en

Create class that extends ViewModel and store your variable in it as LiveData like in this example:

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<List<User>> users;
    public LiveData<List<User>> getUsers() {
        if (users == null) {
            users = new MutableLiveData<List<User>>();
            loadUsers();
        }
        return users;
    }

    private void loadUsers() {
        // Do an asynchronous operation to fetch users.
    }
}
```

Then you can access the viewmodel from the activity and fragments like this.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create a ViewModel the first time the system calls an activity's onCreate() method.
        // Re-created activities receive the same MyViewModel instance created by the first activity.

        MyViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        model.getUsers().observe(this, users -> {
            // update UI
        });
    }
```

For further details check the documentation on the link above.

Comment: An example of how to do this might make this answer clearer.